# Flying with Air Canada in Business class. Do I get access to a lounge at Manchester Airport?

Tags: lounges, air-canada, man

I'm flying to NYC, Business Class next month with my wife.

I know that Manchester Airport doesn't have a Maple Lounge, but do you get access to another lounge?

I tried calling them, but they didn't know! Maybe I just got the new guy.

Comment: Who is "Them"? Air Canada or Manchester airport?

Comment: Yeah "Them" Being Air Canada. @pnuts Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: They usually give you access to another airline's lounge when they don't have one. When they flew from LHR terminal 3 it was SAS, at SFO it is United and was Air France.

Comment: @Dennis I don't believe any Star Alliance airlines have their own lounge at MAN.

Comment: What's your exact route? I couldn't find any Air Canada operated flight between Manchester and any airport in NYC.

Comment: Its Direct MAN->EWR. Having delved a little deeper, it turns out that particular flight is operated by United on behalf of Air Canada. I've flown business with United before, and was .... disappointed (long story).  Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: United has just started their new "Polaris" Business Class.  You should find this flight better than previous ones.

Comment: @jpatokal, Air France is Skyteam. Air Canada used that lounge when they had flights using the (non-Star-Alliance) 'A' gates at SFO, though they've since moved all flights to the 'G' gates where United is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your comments, your flight is actually with United Airlines, not Air Canada.

United Airlines do have not a United Club at Manchester, but they do provide access to a "contract lounge" for customers travelling in Business Class, which is the [Escape Lounge](http://www.manchesterairport.co.uk/at-the-airport/escape-lounges/terminal-2/).

I've used this lounge previously, and whilst it's nothing overly special, it's certainly better than sitting in the terminal itself waiting for your flight.